# "the reasons interest"

Tags: prepositions

*How this situation arose the present volume graphically sets forth, as well as **the reasons interest** in the case has persisted to the present day, exciting a continuing stream of books and articles by both lawyers and laymen.*

I would like to ask whether there would not be a preposition between "reasons" and "interest". If I understand the sentence properly, it say that the book describes in a vivid detail how the situation arose and as well as it describes the reasons for/of interest that people still have in the case. I do not know what preposition to choice but "reasons interest" seems to be odd to me. "Interest reasons" is probably nonsense so I am really confused.

Comment: Are you sure it says "as well as the reasons interest in the case *that* persisted..."?

Comment: {What are the reasons}  interest in the painting persisted even after potential bidders learned it was a fake?  In other words, Why did interest in the painting persist....

Comment: "the reasons interest in the case *that has* persisted" is either a transcription error on your part, or an ungrammatical sentence on the part of the author.

Comment: Good catch, @TRomano The original does **not** include "That" https://books.google.com/books?id=-Gt9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PR11&lpg=PR11&dq=How+this+situation+arose+the+present+volume+graphically+sets+forth,&source=bl&ots=v2jfwNQjbd&sig=S8Z3HrGxT7RidIHK4WbqtWYfyp4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmrffYuN_MAhUBcCYKHWmLCcQQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=How%20this%20situation%20arose%20the%20present%20volume%20graphically%20sets%20forth%2C&f=false

Comment: I am not a nativer but I have a suggestion. Put a comma between reasons and interest abd read it again.

Comment: @sina if you ever see requests for "native input" feel free to ignore it. This site is for everyone.

Comment: There is still a spurious **that** in the quotation. It should read: "....as well as the reasons interest in the case has persisted..."

Comment: @sina, you're misconstruing the sentence.

Comment: @TRoman yes, you are right. I maid a mistake. Without that "that" it is completely understandable.

Comment: I have mistakenly added the "spurious" "that" because I thought that it is the relative clause – interest in the case that/which persiseted…

Comment: If it were a relative clause, we'd need another finite verb with "interest" as the subject, such as "interest [that-clause ], *has resulted* in a stream of books..." or "interest [ that-clause], *excited* a stream of books".

Comment: The inversion in the first statement does not work well, IMO, with "as well as". Normally **as well as** is flanked by peer constituents: "The present volume graphically sets forth {how this situation arose} **as well as** {why interest in the case has persisted}..."  How...why...

Comment: This is my wrong reading of the text: Interest in the case that (interest) has persisted and that (interest) has excited stream of books… So the interest has persisted and interest has excited the stream of books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How this situation arose the present volume graphically sets forth, as
>   well as the reasons interest in the case <strike>that</strike> has
>   persisted to the present day, exciting a continuing stream of books
>   and articles by both lawyers and laymen.

You can understand  "interest in the case has persisted" as a reduced *why*-clause.

"the reasons (why) interest in the case has persisted".

**The reasons people climb Mount Everest are as varied as the climbers themselves.**